# JQuery-UI Hover Show/Hide Multiple DIV's (Same Class, Diff ID's) with Position Fit Function

Tags: html, jquery-ui, hide, show

i have this code

```
var a = $('p a').hover(function() {
        $('#div1').toggle();
    });
$('#div1').position({my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: 'a', collision: 'fit'}).hide();
});
```

It shows / hides and positions **ONLY FOR ONE SPECIFIC DIV** (by ID ) to the text link.

If i have more than one DIV and more links , how can i globalise the hover and position function to apply for ALL DIVS with the SAME CLASS, but DIfferent ID's, with each text link specifically?

Someone told me instead of using

`$('#div1').toggle();`

i could use the Class Selector

`$('.ThisDIV').toggle();`

but this metod is not working to me for more than one DIV...

For ex. i have 2 or more DIV's:

`<div id="div1" class="ThisDIV">`

and

`<div id="div2" class="ThisDIV">`

and two links: **link1** and **link2**.

I want when i hover **LINK1** show **DIV1** and hover **LINK2** show **DIV2**, of course with the Position Function inside the screen (not showing the DIV outside the scree width).

Is so complicated my request...?

Answer (score 0):

You can give common name to your links (to make the difference with other links on the page) and then create exactly the same number of divs with ids `div1, div2,...`. Then use this code:

```
$(function() {
$('a[name="special-link"]').each(function(index) {
    var correspondingDiv = $('#div' + (index + 1));
    $(this).hover(function() {
        correspondingDiv.toggle();
    }); 
    correspondingDiv.position({my: 'left top', at: 'left bottom', of: this, collision: 'fit'}).hide();
});
```

});

Doing so you are iterating through all your links and connects them with corresponding divs.

See [Feeble](http://fiddle.jshell.net/vpdppyxh/2/). Common class is used only for divs styles.